# Grafana inside a webapp without iframe

Tags: angular, grafana, grafana-api

I am trying to bring in some Grafana charts into an Angular Application. I tried with Iframe and it works fine but I am exploring options where I can feed data to grafana APIs in the form of JSON and render the charts inside my Angular application. I am trying to go off with Iframe and see if I can draw grafa charts in my application.

I see a npm library called **grafana-dash-gen** but the documentation is not quite effective to me, how do I consume Grafana APIs to render charts inside my app without Iframe?

Comment: Grafana is not intended to be included as an (SPA) library. It is an app. Of course, it can be possible, but you will need pretty deep Grafana dev knowledge and I would say it will be very hackish approach.

Comment: ah, I see. so there is no better way than using iframes to load them as apps?